# Assertion pos >= 188 mpeg ts

Tags: mpeg2-ts

In function `handle_packet()` of *mpegts.c* (*libavformat*), I got a position of positive value which is lesser than 188. Which cause assertion failure. Could you please tell the reason for this issue and also suggest a solution.

```
pos = avio_tell(ts->stream->pb); // pos giving +ve value less than 188
av_assert0(pos >= TS_PACKET_SIZE). // which cause assertion issue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several causes, mainly:

- The TS file contains some garbage
- A desynchronization occured during your process

Whatever happened, you can retrieve synchronization by skipping bytes until you reach the Transport Packet synchro byte which is `0x47`